# Best way to use datetimepicker with Backbone model?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, marionette, datetimepicker

I'm currently using the jquery datetimepicker inside a backbone view that will have a model tied to it for each datepicker control I use.

I'm not sure what the best way to implement this but there is huge rendering slowness issues if I have more than a few datetimepicker controls in my CompositeView.

Here is my current setup, ideas on ways to make this faster or change would be appreciated.

There looks to be a bottle neck in the JQuery _updateDatePicker code as well.  empty() eventually calls $.cleanData which is a choke.

```
    /* Generate the date picker content. */
     _updateDatepicker: function(inst) {
             this.maxRows = 4; //Reset the max number of rows being displayed (see #7043)
             instActive = inst; // for delegate hover events
             inst.dpDiv.empty().append(this._generateHTML(inst));
```

**Underscore template code:**

```
<div style="float:left;">           
    <div class="lbltext" id="startdate-datepicker"></div>                
</div>
```

**CompositeView onRender:**

```
            onRender: function () {
            // Add datetimepicker               
            var dtp_mod = Page.Module("datetimepicker");

            this.dateTimePickerDailyStart = new dtp_mod.View({
                model: new dtp_mod.Model({
                    CurrentDate: null,
                    LabelText: "Start Date",
                    showTimepicker: false

                }),
                el: this.ui.dailystartdatepicker[0]
            }).on("change.datetimepicker", this._onDateChange, this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright, took a stab at this. See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cardiff/SbDcZ/.

**Demo notes**
It will show two identical views which can be reloaded using a button. This is to demonstrate the `onClose` functionality of the view. It also shows that the views are synced and display the latest set value.

**Datetimepicker specific code**

```
// Itemview (line 16 in jsfiddle)
var movieItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: "li",
    className: 'listItem',
    template: "#movie-list-item",
    ui: {
        dateInput: '.datetimepicker'
    },
    onShow: function () {
        // Invoke the datetimepicker plugin
        this.ui.dateInput.datetimepicker({
            // Lazy init to prevent a lot of instances right away
            lazyInit: true,

            // Proxy the callback function to retain view scope
            onChangeDateTime: $.proxy(this.changeDate, this)
        });
    },
    changeDate: function (dp, $input) {
        this.model.set('date', $input.val());
    },
    onClose: function () {
        // Destroy the datetimepicker plugin
        this.ui.dateInput.datetimepicker('destroy');
    },
    modelEvents: {
        'change:date': 'updateDate'
    },
    updateDate: function () {
        // Check if we need to update the date. 
        var modelDate = this.model.get('date');
        if (modelDate != this.ui.dateInput.val()) {
            this.ui.dateInput.val(modelDate);
        }
    }
});
```

**Implementation notes**

- Define the input element using the `ui` attribute to provide easy access.
- Use of `onShow` method before instantiating the plugin. This assumes the *datetimepicker* plugin is dom-dependent. If you do this in the `onRender` function, dom-dependent plugins may not work as intended.
- Instantiating the plugin using the `lazyInit` option which is supposed to be beneficial in long(er) lists.
- Using a proxy for the `onChangeDateTime` function to stay in the view scope and provide easy access to the view's model.
- Destroy the *datetimepicker* plugin on view closing. This (generally) prevents zombies.
- Listen to `change:date' to check whether the value has changed.
- In `updateDate` first check if we really need to update the value in this view. In this case this check is not really necessary, however if you're using plugins which require re-initialization on value changes or any other heavy actions it may be beneficial to check if you really need to do this.